# Different HDRI Resolutions for Viewport and Render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, hdri

I want to use the 1k version of my hdri for the viewport and the 8k for the render. I know how to set up the hdri for the render, but how can I use the 1k version for the viewport? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this in *Material Preview* mode.  It won't work in any of the other three *Viewport Shading* modes.

- Set *Viewport Shading* to  *Material Preview*.
- Left click the ↓ next to the *Viewport Shading* mode selector in the header.  This will bring up the Viewport Shading menu:

[image: Viewport Shading Menu]

- Left click the gear icon.  This will bring up your preferences, with *Lights* Selected.
- Under *HDRIs* you can add the 1k version of the HDI as a custom world.
- Your HDRI will show up in the list of HDRIs you get when you left click the world sphere in the Viewport Shading Menu
- Left click to select it.
- Make sure that *Scene World* is not selected.